# Ошибка syntax error

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

в строке `$day = date('j', strtotime($event['event_start']));`

```
private function _createEventObj() 
    { 

        $arr = $this->_loadEventData(); 

        $events = array(); 
        foreach ( $arr as $event ){ 
            $day = date('j', strtotime($event['event_start']));

            try 
            {
                $events[$day][] = new Event($event);
            } 
            catch ( Exception $e )
            {
                die ( $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $events;
    }
```

Вроде бы все скобки закрыты.
Пожалуйста, помогите.
Полный код выложил на http://pastebin.com/, называется Calendar.
Очень жду ещё помощи.

Comment: Частично решил, но.
В строке поставив фигурные скобки, вот так: $day = date('j', strtotime({$event['event_start']})); ошибка теперь переместилась в самый конец кода, в строку там где закрывающий - ?>
Ошибка: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Comment: Частичное решение точно неправильное. В этой строке синтаксических не вижу. Единственное, что пришло в голову - либо вы скопировали не то что есть, либо функции "strtotime" нет у вас. 

В смысле я в курсе, что должна быть. Дайте результат от такого кода (вместо проблемной строки)

    die(var_dump(function_exists('strtotime'), $event['event_start']));

Comment: @Sh4dow, несуществующая функция вызывает ошибку несуществующей функции.

В это коде что-нибудь копировалось из внешних источников? Там могут быть непечатные символы?

Comment: Именно этот кусок кода 100% рабочий (имею у себя этот учебный проектик :) ) Подставил в код, скопировав из вопроса один в один в IDE, все фунциклирует! Ищите проблему выше в классе, где-то перемудрили или дайте ввесь код класса Calendar нам на тест, хотя он и довольно длинный.

Comment: Ну и да, если копировали из книжки, а не набивали вручную, то возможно, как говорит @Fike, попались левые символы, которые и сводят с ума интерпретатор

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
@Fike, код писал своими ручками по книге Ленгсторфа. 
Повторно проверил на предмет ошибок незакрытой фигурной скобки, не нашел.

MDJHD, весь код предоставить тут не получится, т. к. есть ограничения на число символов.

Comment: @Kirill  Seleznev http://pastebin.com  
Ближайший [чекер](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) говорит мне, что код вполне валидный. Если вырезать к чертям этот метод, что-нибудь поменяется?

Comment: @Kirill  Seleznev выложите сюда http://pastebin.com, отблагодарить можно только за ответ вроде.

Comment: @Kirill  Seleznev, можно нажать "лайк" возле комментария, который увеличит рейтинг комментарию. Аналогично с ответом, плюс это еще увеличит карму автора. И, наконец, каждый вопрос может иметь один "выбранный ответ" (галка возле рейтинга ответа), который тоже докинет кармы ответившему.

Comment: Уважаемые @Fike и @MDJHD код выложил на http://pastebin.com/, называется Calendar. Очень вас прошу посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Kirill  Seleznev, пожалуйста, предоставьте ссылку на добавленный код.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Cz80SSDY пожалуйста.
Ошибка возникает на строке 348 - $day = date('j', strtotime($event['event_start']));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите все пробелы перед **FORM_MARKUP;** (266-я строка)

**[Синтаксис "here document" не допускает пробелов перед закрывающим идентификатором](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php)**

```
echo <<<END
Здесь используется синтаксис "here document" для вывода
нескольких строк с подстановкой переменных $variable.
Заметьте, что закрывающий идентификатор должен
располагаться в отдельной строке. никаких пробелов!
END;
```

Из-за этой ошибки у вас весь документ после этой строчки считается частью here document.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое @VenZell, со вчерашнего дня парился c этой проблемой.